# how to upload to your code to Google Glass?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm in the process of learning android and the GDK, I have "Android developer tools" installed along with "SDK Manager".

I made my first hello world app, but I don't know how to go about linking up to my Google Glass from my Windows 7 PC to upload the code.

Does anyone have a good tutorial or  step by step instructions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

---

To give more information, I followed the steps on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boj0f_O3i88) to install and prepare a hello world  application which works well on the emulator.

Now that I have the app working on the emulator, i would like to send it to glass but I have nothing (on windows explorer or anywhere else) to sync up to. How can I make my glass device show up on windows O/S so I can have something to work from.

Not seeing the device is my first challenge to getting my hello world app on the glass.

Thanks and my apologies if it sounded like I hadn't done my research.

---

Screenshots of the SDK manager with the correct installation and the DDMS that never shows Glass, even when it's connected to the USB

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is I don't see my Glass device anywhere, I've watched the video, that's why i specified the software I'm using, clearly I'm doing something wrong, i just need a little guidance

Comment: You may want to edit your question to specify the exact steps and commands you've used and what is or isn't working. As your question stands now, it really seems like you haven't tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I couldn't see the Google Glass on my computer.

I followed the instructtion on youtube by a fellow explorer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfpKyj7fJCM

He's got the written version of what he does here: http://leetinsider.com/2013/12/11/google-glass-drivers-windows/

Basically my Fix consisted of adding the following code into my  sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf file:

```
;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

Then I simply updated driver on my unknown device from my "device Manager" and pointed it to the android_winusb.inf file and it worked!

I can now see and upload code to glass!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't put Glass into Debug Mode, so it isn't detected by the `adb` program or graphical equivalent.

You may want to follow the steps at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#for_android_beginners which is a step-by-step guide for deploying on Glass. It should go hand-in-hand with the video you outlined above, but has Glass-specific information as well.

Comment: I have Glass in Debug Mode 100%, and I followed the link you provided with no success. Windows 7 does not show, or the DDMS don't show glass anywhere that i can send the code to. the usb is plugged in ( I will add screenshots to my question for you to see).. i appreciate the help to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my andriod_winusb.inf already had some values under the ;Google Glass line. 
That made the Google Glass device appear in the device manager, but as an "Android ADB Interface" instead of an "Android Composite ADB Interface". Any changes to the andriod_winusb.inf didn't make any difference.

What worked for me was to click on the Andoid ADB Interface in the Device Manager. Click uninstall, and (very important) check the check box that says : "Delete the driver software for this device".

Then I modified the andriod_winusb.inf file, by adding

```
;Google Glass
   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

Then back in the Device manager I clicked on Glass 1 in the Device manager, and updated the driver.

I'm guessing that once Windows knows about a driver, it caches it somewhere, so uninstalling it and reinstalling ,without "deleting the driver software" just brings the cached driver back, and completely disregards the changes in the original driver folder.