# DDMS/ADB not listing Google Glass on Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm just getting started with Glass and am unable to get it pairing with ADT on Mac OSX Mavericks. iPhoto seems to connect and download pics/vids just fine, so there's at least some USB connectivity going on.

**Steps taken:**

1. Enabled debugging on Glass Downloaded ADT and followed the
   instructions here -
   https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#setting_up_the_development_environment
2. Restarted computer
3. Restarted Glass
4. Tried multiple USB ports
5. Tried listing devices both in Eclipse DDMS and from CLI using ADB
6. Said "ok Glass, just connect already"

**Other:**

Mac OSX: 10.9.1
MacBook Pro: Late 2011

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Has anybody experienced this issue and/or have suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem even when debugging was ON. Rebooting and adb kill-server/start-server didn't help. What did was turning debugging on Glass off, and back on.

Comment: Turning on and off the debug mode solve the problem but it doesn't work as a sound device even though it is paired and listed in sound preference. On Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on the Debug mode on your Glass?

Put your Glass in “Debug Mode” in the Settings on the Glass itself. Locate the device info and scroll right to turn Debug Mode on. Then plug your Glass into your computer using the USB micro cable.

After that you should be able to see it from ADT or "adb devices".

---

Do you happen to use an external display on your Mac? I happened to have the similar issue today, trying to connect a Nexus 7 tablet to a Macbook Pro but 'adb devices' doesn't show the device listed. Weird as Mac usually is pretty automatic. The same Nexus 7 shows in another Mac. After quite a while, I unplugged my thunderbolt cable and yes I can see Nexus listed!

Then I plugged back my thunderbolt cable and the device still shows.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. That was the first thing I did after setting up ADT with the correct SDK packages.

Comment: Sorry I missed your very first step :) I tried Glass on 3 similar Macs and they all work fine without additional setup. I also tried Glass on Ubuntu Linux on a Windows partition and it also works without additional setup. Finally I tried Glass on Windows which still works but requires some additional setup as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246941/how-to-upload-to-your-code-to-google-glass. So if possible you may want to try on another Mac or Linux or Windows, to see if there's anything wrong with your Glass or your Mac.

Comment: Jeff, I appreciate the suggestions. Just before reading that comment, I tried it out on a Windows 7 machine and had no problems at all. I must have borked something on my Mac. Maybe Macports? Who knows; I'll report back if I figure it out.

Comment: I'm glad it works on Windows 7 - at least your Glass is good :) I wonder if you any other Android devices that you can see from ADT or 'adt device'? Hope you'll get the problem fixed soon.

Comment: Tried my (old) Android phone - same thing, it isn't recognized. The plot thickens...