# Glass doesn't appear under DDMS in eclipse

Tags: google-glass

I am not able to get my Google Glass on available devices list in Window > Open Perspective > DDMS in eclipse.

What I did - (1) Downloaded 4.0.3 SDK and GDK Sneak Peek (2) Turned on USB debugging on glass (3) Connected glass via USB (4) Opened eclipse and navigated thru' Window > Open Perspective > DDMS. Devices tab is empty and nothing is shown.﻿

OS is Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DDMS unable to see Google Glass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390624/ddms-unable-to-see-google-glass)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to Google Glass on Windows 7 (using ADT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564973/unable-to-connect-to-google-glass-on-windows-7-using-adt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my question is duplicate of something that was asked already! Just found this on stackoverflow - [how to upload to your code to Google Glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246941/how-to-upload-to-your-code-to-google-glass)

It solved my problem!

Comment: Yes, the video was helpful to solve the issue, glad it helped others too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Galaxy S III, I am guessing you did not install the drivers for your device, this website seems to have some troubleshooting advice.
http://glassdev.blogspot.com/