# Unable to connect to Google Glass on Windows 7 (using ADT)

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

**Environment**:
**OS**: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, SP1 (latest patches)
**Hardware**: Dell XPS L702X (8GB Ram)
**Android Developers Tool (ADT)**: version adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030
**Google USB driver**: version 9
**Google Glass**: "v2" device running XE12

***Situation***: Debug mode enabled on Google Glass; connected to USB port on computer; no device seen (ADT cannot find glass).

The android_winusb information already contains the following settings for Glass: in NTx86 section:

```
;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

in NTamd64 section

```
;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

Update: When I open the device manager, I DO see the "Glass 1" device in the "Portable Devices" section and in "Other devices" session.  However, when I open the ADT the Google Glass device is not recognized (even though when I connect my HTC One Kit Kat 4 device shows up, is recognized and I can load an application onto that Android phone).

Suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Does the machine respond at all when you connect it? Are you able to connect with ADB to other android devices? If nothing else, it should show up as a camera.

I know on Windows 8.1 I've had to finagle the driver, uninstalling it and reinstalling it until I got it to say "Android ADB Composite" or whatever.

Comment: Connecting my HTC One Android (KitKat) device via USB allows me to see and run that device. However, connecting Google Glass device results in "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Glass Development Kit Sneak Peak'.  **Help!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally able to connect with Google Glass!  Here are the steps that I used for the environment in question:

1. Installed ADT bundle for 64-bit Windows; updated all (took more than one cycle)
2. Used Android SDK Manager to load API 19 (Kit Kat) and API 15, along with Google Glass Sneak Peak, and ensured current USB driver was updated (to version 9 at this writing)
3. In ADT, added MyFirstApp (for Android phone) and deployed to HTC One/Sprint (running Kit Kat) device [optional, just to ensure that ADT can recognize something]
4. Stopped ADT
5. Opened Device Manager
6. Connected Google Glass, noted "Glass 1" in BOTH the *Portable device* and the *Other device* sections
7. Selected "Glass 1" in the Other device section (not the Portable device section) and ran update driver command pointing to the xxx\GoogleGlass\adt-bundle\sdk\extras folder to search.
8. Completion of driver update moved the device to "*Android devices*" section, noting it is an Android Composite ADB Interface

Once this had completed, I could take a sample application (I used Compass) and ran it as an Android Application!

(Since my device has an automaatic lock -- I assume -- I had to power cycle the device once to be able to get it to respond.)

Comment: This worked for me ! I was reluctant to do the registry and driver hacks on other posts. This worked perfectdly now I can see google glass as an Android Device in Device manager, ad in my ADT in Eclipse !

Comment: Glad this helped someone else! (Shameless plug, you could upvote the question/answer so others in our predicament may find this solution easily.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Glass was showing as SAMSUNG Android phone as well. My steps to fix the issue:

win7:

1. Click on: Update Driver
2. Click on: Browse my computer for driver software
3. Click on: Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
4. Click on: Have Disk... (that options is in the bottom right corner)
5. click on: Browse...
6. navigate to the location of your edited android_winusb.inf driver then click open then click ok then click next
7. wait a moment then you should see "Windows has successfully updated your driver software". then click close and close again.

!!!(now here is the important part)!!!

8. Right click on the device and click uninstall.
9. check the box "Delete the driver software for the device" then click ok
10. wait about 5 sec then unplug your Google Glass from the computer. wait 5 more sec then plug it in.
11. Watch the magic happen!!!! its working!!