# Unable to connect Glass to run gdk samples

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have Glass with version 4.0.4, XE 12.1
I just installed the latest ADT with Android 4.4.2 (API 19) and Glass Development Kit Preview.
My problem is when I try to run samples, DDMS shows the Glass device as being online but when I try to run the application, it gives the following error on the console:
Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.

When the Android Device Chooser window opens, there is no entry for  Glass in the list.

Glass has debug mode turned on and is visible in DDMS but just not compatible for some reason.

This also brings me to a related question. I just received my device in the mail yesterday and left it charging overnight but still has not updated to XE 16. Glass is connected to wifi and the internet is fine on it. What do I need to do to force it to update itself?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664814/cant-run-sample-apps-on-glass-device-not-visible-in-android-device-chooser) similar to yours. Did you get it resolved? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

- First, make sure that your Google Glass is updated to XE16 (connect to your home/business wifi; plugin charging cable). Do not attempt to go further until your Google Glass has updated
- Once that is done, you might look at some of the other answers to "how do I connect".  Some of the steps for this are shown below.

What OS are you using (Windows?). Let me know and I will update the answer with what I had to do to see Google Glass (or [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564973/unable-to-connect-to-google-glass-on-windows-7-using-adt) )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you set the wrong project target.
If you are using Eclipse, open **project.properties** and make sure the target looks like this:

```
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15
```

Not

```
# Project target.
target=android-15
```

You can try:

Open project properties (Alt+Enter) -> Android -> Project Build Target -> Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek

BTW, IMO, Glass update is pretty random. I have no idea how Google decides who gets the update. You can flash the system image if you don't want to wait. Please see https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system. (Warning: Rooting, unlocking, or flashing your Glass voids your warranty.)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Glass is displayed under DDMS shows, it is being detected by ADB. The reason you are not able to run the app on Glass is that, your current version of GDK is not compatible with Glass XE 12.1. If you run projects with Android 4.0, you can see your device listed.

In order to resolve this issue, upgrade Glass XE to the latest and try running the app. Then your device will be listed under currently running devices.

Glass XE will be automatically upgraded. Make sure your device is connected to WIFI, connect device to the charger and restart.